# add jquery event listener to series of unique elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I'm trying to write a function with jQuery that will create a series of new inputs next to a series of unique inputs that already exist. The function should add event listeners to each of the new inputs so that whenever its value changes (something is typed into it, for example), the value of the original input next to it has the same value.

Eventually I will simply hide the original form so that the end user only sees the new form. I'm doing this for the sake of being able to control which parts of the form the user can see/modify and also to have more control over the way the form looks. The reason I have to do all this is because I have to do all this is because I'm modifying a Microsoft Sharepoint item creation form, and the only way to modify it is to add javascript to the page. If there's a better way of doing this I'm all ears. I'm relatively new to coding and very new to coding in Sharepoint.

Anyways, here's what I have:

```
    var inputIdArr = [
    'OrigInput1', 
    'OrigInput2',
    'OrigInput3',
    'OrigInput4',
    'OrigInput5',
    'OrigInput6',
    'OrigInput7'
    ];

function newInputs(arr) {
    for (str in arr) {
        var elem = $( "[id='" + inputIdArr[str] + "']" );
        var parent = elem.parent();
        var newInputId = `newInput${str}`
        var newInput = `<input type='text' id=${newInputId} />`;

        parent.append(newInput);
        $( `[id=${newInputId}]` ).change(function() {
            console.log(newInputId + " changed");
            elem.val($( `[id=${newInputId}]` ).value);
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    newInputs(inputIdArr);
});
```

Currently, the console always logs "newInput7 changed". I'm not sure how to fix it so it logs that the correct new input has changed. I could also use guidance on where to go once that's done.

Comment: use selector like this $("input[id^='OrigInput']") then it will work

Comment: can you please paste html also..

Comment: @KresimirPendic sharepoint HTML is by far the least human-readable HTML I've ever seen. It really wouldn't be very helpful.

Comment: so you can jquery? any version?

Comment: @SudarpoChong if there's a CDN for it I can use it. I didn't include that in the code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatically keeping track of the generated ids of dynamically created elements is an anti-pattern that leads to needlessly verbose code and a maintenance headache.

Instead you can make the logic much more succinct and extensible by simply using classes and DOM traversal to group and relate elements to each other, something like this:

```js
$('input.orig').after('<input type="text" class="appended" />');

$('#container').on('input', 'input.appended', function() {
  $(this).prev('.orig').val(this.value);
})
```

```css
.appended {
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" class="orig" />
  <input type="text" class="orig" />
  <input type="text" class="orig" />
</div>
```

Also note that using attribute selectors to find elements by id is redundant when the `#` id selector is available and much faster - even though it's not needed for this to work.

Comment: nicely done! i agree on the id-maintenance headache part

Comment: here's an example of what one of the ids look like:" 'Title_fa376e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0288e6ddd247_$TextField' "

That's why I originally had them in an array originally. The ids for all the inputs are seemingly randomly-generated. I should have clarified this before. what if I use jQuery to add the same class to each element? I suppose I would have to manually track the ids still.

Comment: Not at all. The code above is completely agnostic of the `id` attributes - which is the whole point. You already have access to the relevant inputs via `$(this)` and `$(this).prev('.orig')`. You don't need the `id` at all.

Comment: Ah okay. I was confused before but I got it to work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should give you rought start,, I've created 7 original fields, and your function does new fields successfully. I've added event or binding on new fields outside of your loop because there was some issue I think.

```js
// fields selection
var inputIdArr = [
  'OrigInput1',
  'OrigInput2',
  'OrigInput3',
  'OrigInput4',
  'OrigInput5',
  'OrigInput6',
  'OrigInput7'
];
// function for creating new fields
function newInputs(arr) {
  for (str in arr) {
    var elem = $("[id='" + inputIdArr[str] + "']");
    var parent = elem.parent();
    var newInputId = `newInput${str}`
    var newInput = `<input type='text' id=${newInputId} />`;
    parent.append(newInput);
  }
}
// create new inputs on dom ready
$(document).ready(function() {
  newInputs(inputIdArr);
});

// bind new inputs and send value to org inputs
$(document).on('input', '[id^="newInput"]', function(el){
  $(this).prev().val( $(this).val() );
});
```

```css
input:nth-child(1){ border:1px solid red; }
input:nth-child(2){ border:1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><input type="text" id="OrigInput1"></div>
<div><input type="text" id="OrigInput2"></div>
<div><input type="text" id="OrigInput3"></div>
<div><input type="text" id="OrigInput4"></div>
<div><input type="text" id="OrigInput5"></div>
<div><input type="text" id="OrigInput6"></div>
<div><input type="text" id="OrigInput7"></div>
```